# Tying it all together, Directory Recursive Search + Events + Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion, io

What I would like to do, and have worked towards developing, is a standard class which I can use for retrieving all sub-directories (and their sub directories and files, and so on) and files.

```
WalkthroughDir(Dir)
  Files a
  Folders b
  WalkthroughDir(b[i])
```

A straightforward recursive directory search.

Using this as a basis I wanted to extend it to fire events when:

- A file is found;
- A directory is found;
- The search is completed

  ```
  private void GetDirectories(string path)
  {
      GetFiles(path);

      foreach (string dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
      {
          if (DirectoryFound != null)
          {
              IOEventArgs<DirectoryInfo> args = new IOEventArgs<DirectoryInfo>(new DirectoryInfo(dir));
              DirectoryFound(this, args);
          }

          // do something with the directory...

          GetDirectories(dir, dirNode);
      }
  }

  private void GetFiles(string path)
  {
      foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
      {
          if (FileFound != null)
          {
              IOEventArgs<FileInfo> args = new IOEventArgs<FileInfo>(new FileInfo(file));
              FileFound(this, args);
          }

          // do something with the file...
      }
  }
  ```

Where you find the comments above ("do something[...]") is where I might add the file or directory to some data structure.

The most common factor in doing this type of search though is the processing time, particularly for large directories. So naturally I wanted to take this yet another step forward and implement threading. Now, my knowledge of threading is pretty limited but so far this is an outline of what I've come up with:

```
    public void Search()
    {
        m_searchThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SearchThread));
        m_searching = true;
        m_searchThread.Start();
    }

    private void SearchThread()
    {
        GetDirectories(m_path);
        m_searching = false;
    }
```

If I use this implementation, assign the events in a control it throws errors (as I expected) that my GUI application is trying to access another thread.

Could anyone feedback on this implementation as well as how to accomplish the threading. Thanks.

**UPDATE (selkathguy recommendation):**

This is the adjusted code following selkathguy's recommendation:

```
    private void GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo path)
    {
        GetFiles(path);

        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in path.GetDirectories())
        {
            if (DirectoryFound != null)
            {
                IOEventArgs<DirectoryInfo> args = new IOEventArgs<DirectoryInfo>(dir);
                DirectoryFound(this, args);
            }

            // do something with the directory...

            GetDirectories(dir);
        }
    }

    private void GetFiles(DirectoryInfo path)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in path.GetFiles())
        {
            if (FileFound != null)
            {
                IOEventArgs<FileInfo> args = new IOEventArgs<FileInfo>(file);
                FileFound(this, args);
            }

            // do something with the file...
        }
    }
```

Original code time taken: 47.87s

Altered code time taken: 46.14s

Answer (score 1):

To address the first part of your request about raising your own events from the standard class: you can create a delegate to which other methods can be hooked as callbacks for the event.  Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx as a good resource.  It's fairly trivial to implement.

As for threading, I believe that would be unnecessary at least for your performance concerns.  Most of the bottleneck of performance for recursively checking directories is waiting for the node information to load from the disk.  Relatively speaking, this is what takes all of your time, as fetching a directory info is a blocking process. Making numerous threads all checking different directories can easily slow down the overall speed of your search, and it tremendously complicates your application with the management of the worker threads and delegation of work shares.  With that said, having a thread per disk might be desirable if your search spans multiple disks or resource locations.

I have found that something as simple as recursion using `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()` was one of the fastest solutions, as it takes advantage of the caching that Windows already does.  A search application I made using it can search tens of thousands of filenames and directory names per second.

Comment: So I substituted the string with DirectoryInfo and using the method you suggested. After running both, with my original implementation it took 478717867 ticks and with your suggestion it took 461456141. There doesn't seem to be a major difference in either. 

With regard to threading I would assume there would be only one thread running, i.e. the "m_searchThread". Obviously creating new instances of the class would generate more, but I don't think that's such a burden.

Comment: I've updated the post to include the updated so you can see what it looks like and whether this matches your intention.

Comment: Like I said, the main performance problem will be the physical disk, not your application in this case. As for the threading, if I understand you correctly you need another thread because you're running this from the UI thread, and you don't want to block that, understandably.  I've done something similar with a UI-based search, whereby I created a search thread, then just used occasional `lock`ing around a progress variable and checked at a set interval from the calling UI thread.  Not the most elegant, but it is very simple and it works well enough.

Comment: I think it's been proven, as I suspected that recursion-is-recursion, it's going to take a while regardless of using a string to call the static "GetDirectories" or creating a DirectoryInfo instance and retrieving it. Even if it does save me near enough a whole ~1 second! 

What I'm aiming for is a generic class for directory searching. So I need to keep it generic as possible, including the threading model for searching. Do you have any concrete examples, code references, etc.? As I stated, my knowledge of threading is limited so I need something a little more concrete.

Comment: Absolutely!  http://pastebin.com/QM87TQci
Do note that the example I gave includes features that you may or may not need, as it's simply a direct excerpt from my code.